# Insert or update on table "items" violates foreign key constraint "items_seller_id_fkey"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert **seller_id** when seller create a new item. The **seller_id** come from request context from session. I keep getting the ***insert or update on table "items" violates foreign key constraint "items_seller_id_fkey"***.

The query for insert is:

```
INSERT INTO items (name, description, seller_id , created)
VALUES($1, $2, $3, current_timestamp)
RETURNING id
```

The schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE sellers (
 id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,  
 name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE items (
 id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
 seller_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES sellers ON DELETE CASCADE,
 name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 description VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
 );
```

Comment: and what is unclear in this message? You try to insert into items seller_id which is absent in the table sellers

Comment: I'm trying to refer the seller_id to the primary key in sellers table and the id exists as the seller already created. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And the error message is telling you there is no `sellers.id` that matches the `seller_id`. Take that as the truth and work backwards to determine why that is the case? Two choices that come to mind:  a) `seller_id` from the request is not what you think it is. b) You are inserting into the wrong table.